# How can I convert a datetime into number of months in t-sql?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

If I have a datetime field (like Birthdate) in Sql Server, and I want to convert that value to the total number of months up to now, how can I do this in T-Sql?

To be clear, I'm not looking for the monthpart of Birthdate, but rather this date converted to total number of months up to a certain date (lets take 'now' as an example).

Comment: I thought you wanted the difference in months and not just the monthpart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DATEDIFF(M, '1970-03-01', GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DATEDIFF(M, BIRTHDATEHERE, TODAY)
```

So a working example would be

```
Select DATEDIFF(M, '1977-12-01', GETDATE())
```